# Costumizing loss function in keras with condition

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

I want to setup a keras model (tensorflow backend) for a multiclassification problem with 4 different classes. I  have both labeled and unlabeled data.

I have worked out the case in which I only train with the labeled data and my model looks something like this:

```
# create model
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(len(config.variables), ))  
X = layers.Dense(units=200, activation="relu")(inputs)
output = layers.Dense(units=4, activation="softmax", name="output")(X)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(1e-4), loss=loss_function, metrics=["accuracy"])

# train model
model.fit(
    x=train_data, 
    y=train_class_labels,
    batch_size=200, 
    epochs=200, 
    verbose=2, 
    validation_split=0.2,
    sample_weight       = class_weights
    )
```

I have functioning models with to different losses namely `categorical_crossentropy` and `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, and depending on the loss function my `train_class_labels` where in one-hot representation (e.g. [ [0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,1], ...]) or in the integer representation (e.g. [0,0,2,1,0,3, ...]) and everything worked fine. `class_weights` is some weight vector ([0.78, 1,34, ...])

**Now for my further plans I need to include the unlabeled data in the training process but I need it to be ignored by the loss function.**

What I have tried:

1. setting the labels from the unlabeled data to [0,0,0,0] when using `categorical_crossentropy` as a loss, because i thought then my unlabeled data would be ignored by the loss function. Somehow this changed the predictions after training.
2. I also tried setting the weights from the unlabeled data to 0 but that did have an effect either

I concluded that I need to somehow mark me unlabeled data and customize my loss function so that it can be told to ignore those samples. Something like

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    if y_true == labeled data:
        return normal loss function
    if y_true == unlabeled data:
        return 0
```

Those are some snippets that I have found but they do not seem to work:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    return K.switch(K.flatten(K.equal(y_true, -1)), K.zeros_like(loss), loss)

def custom_loss2(y_true, y_pred):
    idx  = tf.not_equal(y_true, -1)
    y_true = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, idx)
    y_pred = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, idx)
    return losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```

In those examples I set the labels from the unlabeled data to -1 so `train_class_labels` would look something like this: [0,-1,2,0,3, ... ]

But when using the first loss function I  just get Nans and when using the second one I get the following error:
`Invalid argument: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [1,5000] and labels shape [5000]`

Comment: Please be reasonable; including your unlabeled data in the *training* process while at the same time trying to *ignore* them during training does not make any sense. At all.

Comment: @desertnaut I know that that seems strange, but the data I am using is collision data from particle physics. The labeled dataset is from a simulation and the unlabeled data from a real collision. The thing is that I am going to implement another output to the network which shall classify the domain (so if its simulated or real data), and right in front of this output there is a layer which flips the gradient. The goal is to get domain invariant features from the dataset. The problem I described in my question is the setup work, as I understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that setting the labels to [0,0,0,0] would be just fine. Because the loss is calculated by sum of the log losses of your instances per class (in your case the loss would be 0 for instances with no label).

I don't understand why you are inserting non labeled data in your training in a supervised setting.

I think that the differences that you obtain are due to the batch size and to the gradient step. If there are instances that do not contribute to the gradient descent, the loss calculated would be different than before, and then you get the difference in prediction.

Basically there would be less informative instances per batch.

If you use as batch size the size of all the dataset there would be no difference from a previous training without the unlabeled instances (but always with a training with batch size = size of the dataset)

Comment: @desertnaut In the crossentropy calculations, the labels are used in the sum. If the labels are all 0, the loss would be 0. Am I wrong?

https://i.ibb.co/4tCVTGw/losscalculatincrossentropy.png

Comment: You are right, my bad - did not express myself correctly. What I should have said is that by using all-0s, the instances are no more *unlabeled* - they are now implicitly *labeled* as an extra class, which, moreover, is not included in the initial one-hot encoding. And by giving a loss of 0 (as you correctly describe), the process signals "*this is a correctly classified sample*"; does this make any sense as a practice?

Comment: Ok, I get how this can cause trouble. But wont I have the sampe problem if I set the batch size to all the dataset. As I understand it I still would have less informative instances and therefore the gradient step would be different?

Comment: @King5ters if you use all the dataset the gradient step would be the same. Because the gradient calculated on losses that are 0 is always 0, so it will not contribute to the final result. This changes when you use batches. Depending on what you have inside the batch, there will be a step toward the error reduction. But now in the batches there are also non informative instances, so the step per batch will be different

Comment: @King5ters because there are in a batch less informative instances 
. Before you got all informative instances per batch, now you get also a portion with non informative instances, so the gradient would have less errors on which the gradient is calculated.

Comment: @King5ters to make it more clear, it would be like having smaller batches on the previous setup without non informative instances

Comment: @King5ters this doesn't mean that you'll get worse performance, but only a different one. It depends on the context how it will affect the training

Comment: @King5ters I'll link an answer I gave in the past, regarding how batch / mini-batch gradient works https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/488017/understanding-mini-batch-gradient-descent/488074#488074

Comment: @Nikaido Ok thank youvery much, that was a really clear explanation!